# Understanding iterator's behavior for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I wrote the following simple example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{ 
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 4, 7, 10};
    std::vector<int> vect;
    vect.assign(arr, arr + 5);
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "-------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75dd2d97a092ffae)**

And both two loops prints the same. My question is is it reliable? Does iterating over the vector return elemtns in the same order every time? I mean, is it standartized or some implementations are allowed to iterating over a vector in the different order. For instance, we iterate over the vector for the firt time as follows:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

and get the output

```
1
2
4
7
10
```

Whilst, iterating for the second time produce the output:

```
2
10
1
4
7
```

Is that possible for some implementation?

Comment: is it reliable?: As long as the contents of a STL container doesn't change you'll get the same output each time you iterate through it. This is guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: No I don't think so - 'cos those vectors would internally be implemented as arrays or LinkedList - mostly Arrays (resizable) and trying to do something that changes every time is hard for an implementation to do. Unless you want it so! :) In that case you write your own! :)

Comment: Is the output really different? I ran your code on [CodeChef IDE](http://www.codechef.com/ide) and the output is same.

Comment: @gabhijit they must be implemented as contiguous storage

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, it's reliable.**

A vector is a "sequence container", which means its ordering is deterministic. You choose the order of the elements in the container, and that's the order you get out of it when you iterate. Always.

- You populate the vector with elements that live at *index 0* to *index N-1*;
- A vector's iterator iterates from *index 0* to *index N-1*.

It's completely analogous to walking forwards through an array, in that sense.

Funnily enough, even the associative containers have a reliable iteration order; even though the element ordering is performed by an algorithm using a *comparator* (which you may specify and, if you don't, it's `std::less`) rather than simply by virtue of the order in which you appended elements.

You can always rationalise about the iteration order of a standard container.

Comment: I wonder if that can also be answered in a language-lawyer-safe way ;) The specification of the insertion functions is not very formal, and does not seem to relate to the accessor functions.

Comment: @dyp: Yeah I decided not to go down that route and I was hoping to have gotten away with it ;p

Comment: The unordered associative containers have reliable iteration order?

Comment: @NirFriedman: Ooh-er, I didn't think about those. Still, I think they _must_ do, if only via "indirection" of a kind through the hashing layer. (Honestly, I have no idea.)

Comment: @NirFriedman Depends on what you mean by *reliable*. The observable behaviour must not change when not calling member functions that mutate the state of the container. This includes the order of iteration, as far as I can tell. However, inserting an element into an unordered associative container can cause rehashing, which might produce a different iteration order.

Comment: I think we can take as read that mutating a container will alter what you get back when you iterate over it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's not the guarantee you're looking for *waveshand*

Comment: @dyp: No but it's a stronger guarantee so who cares ;)

Comment: Huh? That guarantee says *mutation of the container (M) => change of obs behaviour when iterating (I)*, however OP's looking for *¬M => ¬I*. From the former, we can only conclude that *¬I => ¬M*

Comment: @dyp: But we're no longer talking about what the OP wants! #ducks Yeah my terminology was wrong. I was trying to make a jovial "it won't matter anyway so who cares" point.

Comment: @dyp: A forward iterator has the multipass property, which essentially says that you can iterate as many times as you like from the same iterator and you'll get the same things in the same order. (If the iterator is invalidated, all bets are off, of course.) Sequence container iterators are required to be (at least) forward iterators; associative container iterators to be (at least) bidirectional iterators; unordered associative container iterators to be (at least) forward iterators.

Comment: To recap, I can itarate over any container any time and give the same iteration order, is that right?

Comment: @dyp Yes, I agree. I would think that a given container would have to satisfy determinism, and various other conditions related to which methods are allowed to invalidate existing iterators. I was just surprised at Lightness Races in Orbit's (forever hereon abbreviated as LRiO) assertion, and thought maybe he knew something I didn't. AFAIK as well the unordered associative containers do not require </comparator to be defined for types they contain.

Comment: @St.Antario: Provided you don't modify the container in between iterations.

Comment: @Nir: What, the phrase "honestly, I have no idea" wasn't a clue? ;)

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` guaranteed continuous memory allocation like an array. So accessing the vector using iterator always guaranteed  in same order of elements of a `std::vector`